# Help with simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector-calculus

Could anyone please help me simply the following expression

```
   (1/(1 + a + c) + 1/(1 + b + c) - 3/(3 + 2*a + 2*b + 2*c))*
 (1 - c - ((a*b - c)*(a^2 + b^2 + b*(-1 + c) + (-1 + c)*c + 
            a*(-1 + b + c - 3*b*c)))/(-6*a*b*c + c^2 + 
   b^2*(1 + c^2) + 
         a^2*(1 + b^2 + c^2))) + (1/(1 + a + b) + 1/(1 + b + c) - 
    3/(3 + 2*a + 2*b + 2*c))*
 (1 - b + ((b - a*c)*(a^2 + b^2 + b*(-1 + c) + (-1 + c)*c + 
            a*(-1 + b + c - 3*b*c)))/(-6*a*b*c + c^2 + 
   b^2*(1 + c^2) + 
         a^2*(1 + b^2 + c^2))) + (1/(1 + a + b) + 1/(1 + a + c) - 
    3/(3 + 2*a + 2*b + 2*c))*
 (1 - a + ((a - b*c)*(a^2 + b^2 + b*(-1 + c) + (-1 + c)*c + 
            a*(-1 + b + c - 3*b*c)))/(-6*a*b*c + c^2 + 
   b^2*(1 + c^2) + 
         a^2*(1 + b^2 + c^2)))
```

with

```
1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2 a b c - c^2=0
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When I scrape-n-paste your code I find pale red `)` and `(` showing mismatches. Can you possible scrape-n-paste the code from the screen into your notebook and correct those? Thanks

Comment: @Bill  Okay, revised. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know there is much simpler expression when `1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2 a b c - c^2 == 0`? when you do `Simplify[expr,1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2 a b c - c^2 == 0]` it does not simplify.

Comment: Or could anyone simplify the expression to an expression whose sign can be determined for all a, b, c satisfying $1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2a b c - c^2=0$, $a+b>-1$, $a+c>-1$, and $b<0$? Thanks.

Comment: @Bill   Thank you for your comment, but could you transform  it to an expression whose sign can be determined for all a, b, c satisfying $1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2a b c - c^2=0$, $a+b>-1$, $a+c>-1$, and $b<0$? Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** (now regarding all conditions)

Seems impossible to find a simple form of the given expression due to the complicated form.

Regard the hypersurface where expr is greater or lower zero with regard of all conditions.

```
cpg = ContourPlot3D[1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2 a b c - c^2 == 0, 
{a, -1, 10}, {b, -10, 0}, {c, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> 300, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b, c}, 
  a + b > -1 && a + c > -1 && b < 0 && expr[a, b, c] > 0]]
```

[image]

```
cpl = ContourPlot3D[1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2 a b c - c^2 == 0, 
{a, -1, 10}, {b, -10, 0}, {c, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> 300, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b, c}, 
a + b > -1 && a + c > -1 && b < 0 && expr[a, b, c] < 0]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your plot, and from your plot, can you see that the values of the expression is always >0 for all a, b and c satisfying a + b > -1 && a + c > -1 && b < 0? Thanks.

Comment: and so, can you show that the the expression is always >0 for all a, b and c satisfying a + b > -1 && a + c > -1 && b < 0 and 1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2 a b c - c^2=0 by transforming the expression? Thanks a lot.

Comment: and so, can you show that the the expression is always >0 for all a, b and c satisfying a + b > 0&& a + c > 0 && b < 0 and 1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2 a b c - c^2=0 by transforming the expression? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This `{{amin, amax}, {bmin, bmax}, {cimn, 
   cmax}} = {First@
      Minimize[{#, a + b > -1 && a + c > -1 && b < 0}, {a, b, c}], 
     First@Maximize[{#, a + b > -1 && a + c > -1 && b < 0}, {a, b, c},
        Reals]} & /@ {a, b, c} // Quiet ` shows the minima/maxima for a,b,c. Yileds `{{-1, \[Infinity]}, {-\[Infinity], 0}, {-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}} ` .

Comment: If you change to `a + b > 0 && a + c > 0 && b < 0 ` , you get `{{0, \[Infinity]}, {-\[Infinity], 0}, {-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}} ` .

Comment: Even for `a + b > 0 && a + c > 0 && b < 0 ` there are regions of expr, where it is < 0.  `RegionPlot3D[
  g1[a, b, c] < 0 && a + b > 0 && a + c > 0 && b < 0, {a, -1, 
   10}, {b, -10, 0}, {c, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
  ImageSize -> 300] // Quiet ` .

Comment: I said "and 1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2 a b c - c^2=0". So how about  a + b > -1 && a + c > -1 && b < 0 &&1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2 a b c - c^2=0? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please let me know what does the # in you command mean? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't take the equation condition into account. Made an edit to my post.